# hide a div in specific custom taxonomy category

Tags: wordpress, css, categories, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I was working on site pages **[here](http://webzer.comxa.com/listing/mr-mrs-mullah/)** which comes in wedding category which comes in a custom taxonomy named listing.In my wedding category listing i dont want to display the price sticker but it shoud display in all other listing posts eg **[this page](http://webzer.comxa.com/listing/book/)**

I have tried

```
if ( in_category( 'wedding' )) {
?><style>.pricestricker{display:none!important;}</style><?php
}?>
```

also

```
if ( is_category( 'wedding' )) {
?><style>.pricestricker{display:none!important;}</style><?php
}?>
```

also

```
if ( has_term('listing', 'wedding' )) {
?><style>.pricestricker{display:none!important;}</style><?php
}?>
```

none of these worked.Please help.Thank You

Comment: Do you know that where the "pricestricker" div is present on which page ?If yes then try my answer given below

Answer (score 0):

Please try this once where the div "pricestricker" is present:

```
<div class="pricestricker" <?php if ( in_category( 'wedding' )) { echo 'style="display:none;"' }?>><span itemprop="price" class="wlt_shortcode_price">$0</span></div>
Here you should only write the php code inside the div "pricestricker" and remain will be default code.
```

or you can do:

```
   <?php if ( !in_category( 'wedding' )) { ?>
            <div class="pricestricker"><span itemprop="price" class="wlt_shortcode_price">$0</span></div> // This will be your default code
   <?php } ?>
```